# slack and bitbucket integration to create issue in slack

Tags: slack

Is Slack able to create issue to Bitbucket? or Slack just a notification tools only? If it is possible to create issue, and idea how to do it. I only able to get notification from the slack.

From the webhook it have the permission to create issue, but I can't create it via Slack, it does not recognize any command.

What I want to accomplish with my team is I able create an issue directly from slack. e.g we are on #projectA, when we on the discussion on an issue, I can immediately create a command `/issue Bug found here, please fix it`. I do not need to go to website and create the issue, I think this can speed up the production.

So far I integrate with BitBucket, it just show the notification from people commit.

Comment: This is more an web application question it seems? Slack is not really "just a notification" service. It's a Team Messaging Platform (their words). Further more you might want to check up on how to write good questions because your question contains little detail and no information of whenever you checked the documentation or actually tried to implement something along the lines yourself.

Comment: I am thinking someone maybe had implemented already, and it should be more than just notification. So I am looking for expert to give some input on this matter.